# how to show total count of all approved status in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this data where each system have many lines. It also includes the type, status and date.
The status are complete, incomplete, in progress, not yet started.
I need to count how many system that the lines are in type 'B' and the status are ALL APPROVED based on the system and date.

I have tried:

```
select system, date, count(line) from project_system
where type = 'B'
group by system, date 
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'APPROVED'
```

by the script above I still did not get the desired results. The result gives me the system that the status are already ALL APPROVED but with the count of total lines. It shows like this:

```
system   date       count
1       19-20-12      4
2       19-20-12      12
3       19-20-12      6
1       19-21-12      3
2       19-21-12      1
```

I expect to see something like:

```
 date       count
19-20-12      3
19-21-12      2
```

how should I change my query?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Since you have `GROUP BY system, date` you get a separate result for each `system`.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY system, date` means you get a separate row for each pair of system and date.

Use that as a subquery, and then group by date in the main query to get the counts by date.

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS fount
FROM (
    select system, date
    from project_system
    where type = 'B'
    group by system, date 
    having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'APPROVED'
) AS x
GROUP BY date
```

There's no need to get the counts in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a single aggregation query:

```
select date,
       ( count(distinct system) -
        count(case when status <> 'APPROVED' then system end)
       ) as num_approved_only
from project_system
where type = 'B'
group by date ;
```

The idea is to count the distinct systems and subtract from that count the number of systems that have a status other than `'APPROVED'`.